# Space complexity of pushing n elements onto a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Say I have an input size of n, and these n elements are pushed onto a vector.

I recently starting learning about space complexity, but I'm a bit confused. So it looks at memory usage, but this is dynamically allocated memory?

```
vector<int> v;
```

Although this doesn't use the "new" keyword, I read a vector is actually dynamically allocated when you push, so would this mean the space complexity would simply be O(n)?

Comment: `vector<int> v;` declares an object v of type vector<int> without passing any constructor parameters. This means it calls the default constructor (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), which allocates a 0-sized vector. It might internally call `new int[0];` (which is a valid `new` call).

Comment: Also, if you KNOW you will have n elements, you might be better off (instead of pushing) to start the vector at size n (resize, or using the 1-parameter constructor), and putting the elements in as if the vector was an `int[]` array.

Comment: @leewangzhong A zero-sized vector doesn't mean a vector with 0 capacity. IIRC, the implementation can create a capacity > 0 for the default ctor.

Comment: It might call new even if you don't start with any elements, is my point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the space complexity of a `std::vector` is linear in its `size()` (or actually its `capacity()`). Note that while the `std::vector` object itself can be statically or dynamically allocated, its data contents will always be dynamically allocated. *(As @DyP pointed out in the comments, how the allocation actually happens depends on the allocator you use for the vector. But the default allocator uses dynamic allocation).*

Comment: *"its data contents will always be dynamically allocated"* when using the default allocator.

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity of a std::vector is linear in its size, since the underlying structure is as C-array.

However, when you declare

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

an empty container is constructed. If a reallocation happens, the reallocation is itself up to linear in the entire size.

If you know the size of your array in advance, you can use [reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) so as not to (implicitly) reallocate each time you insert an element with `push_back()`.